# Python Matplotlib get_xticklabels in Jupyter Notebook - why does it return a blank list in same cell as plot code?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

**Summary of Problem:**
I am developing a Jupyter notebook as a template for using a new package. For data visualization, I am trying to plot with both date strings and names of experiments as x-axis tick labels. Sometimes, these plots result in crowded x-axes. I am trying to write a function that allows users to every second label (and tick mark), third label, etc. based on input step size. The simple function looks like this:

```
def run_number_labels(axes, label_list, stepsize):
    '''
    This function changes a plot to plot on run numbers. The stepsize determines 
    how many labels to display, use larger numbers for more concentrated data sets
    (1 is every 1, 2 is every 2, and 5 is every 5 labels, for instance). Care should
    be taken to ensure that the length of the label_list is the same as the amount
    of x-axis ticks. This can be verified by running print(axes.get_xticks()) in 
    your notebook. 
    '''
    axes.set_xticks(axes.get_xticks()[::stepsize])
    b = axes.set_xticklabels(labels=label_list[::stepsize], rotation=55, ha='right')
```

This works in most cases, however I have noticed a bug (?) in Jupyter notebooks that is hindering my testing.

*So far, I cannot simply get x-axis tick labels and print them within a cell!*

**What I've Tried:**
I offer the test code below:

```
x = np.linspace(0,10*math.pi,50)
print(x.shape)
y1 = []
y2 = []
for ind, val in enumerate(x):
    y1.append(math.sin(val))
    y2.append(math.cos(val+math.pi))

print(np.array(y1).shape)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)
ax[0].plot(x, np.array(y1), linestyle='-', color='lightgreen')
ax[1].plot(x, np.array(y2), linestyle='-', color='rosybrown')

#Now get the list of xlables
label_list = ax[1].get_xticklabels()
print(label_list)
```

This produces a simple plot within a matplotlib subplots array with a shared x-axis. It attempts to name a list of label strings, `label_list`, from the second, or bottom, x-axis. The plot works, the list, however is not generated:
[image: Subplot with two rows and one column, shared x-axis ranging from 0-30 in steps of 5.]

The list of x-axis labels that is returned is as follows:
`[Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, '')]`

In other words, it is blank.

If I generate the list in the next cell with the same line of code, I get:
`[Text(-5.0, 0, '−5'), Text(0.0, 0, '5'), Text(5.0, 0, '15'), Text(10.0, 0, '25'), Text(15.0, 0, '35'), Text(20.0, 0, ''), Text(25.0, 0, ''), Text(30.0, 0, ''), Text(35.0, 0, '')]`

However, in the next cell, I cannot seem to visualize the graph using the same axes. I have read that the plt.draw() function is supposed to enable this capacity in a Jupyter notebook, however this command returns an error due to an unspecified renderer.

*Are there any work-arounds that can allow me to see the list of x-axis labels in the same cell of a Jupyter notebook?*

**Edit**
*Coup's answer which recommends using `plt.show()` before requesting the list of axis labels works to get the list. However, I cannot manipulate the axes (for instance, using the run_number_labels function above and passing it the list of labels). Is there a way to re-manipulate the axes after plt.show()?* If not, I will need a different way than Coup's answer to tackle this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding plt.show() before defining label_list works.

[image]

```
x = np.linspace(0,10*math.pi,50)

y1 = []
y2 = []
for ind, val in enumerate(x):
    y1.append(math.sin(val))
    y2.append(math.cos(val+math.pi))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)
ax[0].plot(x, np.array(y1), linestyle='-', color='lightgreen')
ax[1].plot(x, np.array(y2), linestyle='-', color='rosybrown')

plt.show()

#Now get the list of xlables
label_list = ax[1].xaxis.get_majorticklabels()
print(label_list)
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, however I've noted that I cannot manipulate the axes anymore after the `plt.show()` command. In other words, I cannot use every 2 axis labels or rotate them to make space for more. So, I've edited my original question to be more specific as you've answered the first part, but I was wrong in assuming that that answer would enable me to do the rest!

Comment: Tell me if I am understanding correctly. You want a function that can space out the x tick labels if they are too long and are overlapping? And you would like to access the x labels to see how long they are, then you will change the x tick labels? 

It sounds like you need tick locators and tick formatters. If you use fixed formatter you are in direct control of tick labels. set_xticks is simply wrapper for these functions. 


https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have latest matplotlib you can do fig.draw_no_output() which is a wrapper of fig.canvas.draw().